# How can I safely email documents and images to Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

My company blocks Google Drive in the browser so I need another way to save documents offsite.  Ideally I'd like to email them.

My former backup strategy was SugarSync and they assigned an email addy to my account that allowed it.  I'm wondering if Drive has a similar feature since I cannot navigate to Drive at work.

Answer (score 2):

There's no native way to email documents to Google Drive. You'll need a third-party tool.

I would use [If This Then That](http://ifttt.com) (IFTTT). By combining the right channels you can get the attachments from an email message into your Google Drive.

There are a couple of ways to go about it. Since you're using Google Drive, you presumably have a Gmail account. There are already several recipes that will take attachments (under the right circumstances) and save them to Drive for you, such as this one: [Save new email attachments to Google Drive](https://ifttt.com/recipes/99068-save-new-email-attachments-to-google-drive). Essentially, it looks for one or more attachments on any email received at your Gmail address and saves it into the Google Drive folder you designate. By using a slightly different trigger, you can have it only save attachments with messages from your work address or with certain keywords in the subject. (Use the "[New mail in inbox from search](https://ifttt.com/channels/gmail/triggers/87-new-email-in-inbox-from-search)" trigger with `has:attachment` and whatever other search term you need.)

Another way to do it, without getting email involved, is to use the [Email](https://ifttt.com/email) channel and the right trigger.

You could certainly just send email to `trigger@recipe.ifttt.com` and have it fire, but then you're precluding using the same trigger for other recipes. I suggest using the "Send IFTTT an email tagged" trigger.

Then, the action is simply to save to Google Drive.

Of course, you'll need to send the email *from* the email address associated with your IFTTT account in order for it to work.

I've created [a recipe](https://ifttt.com/view_embed_recipe/455208-send-email-with-a-gdrive-tag-and-save-attachment-to-google-drive) which does just that.

Comment: @Rubén: Well, yes, if one is able to "save to Drive" from in Gmail, but I got the impression that that won't work for the Asker.

Comment: If you've found that this solved the problem for you, the way to show that to future readers is to use the "Accept" checkmark next to the answer. More information in the [Help Center](/help/someone-answers).